# Remove mini cart menu from sidebar and redirect to checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using theme called [Blance](https://themeforest.net/item/blance-clean-minimal-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/20846862) on [my site](http://bossiopro.com/product/lattice-bodysuit/), but want to remove right sidebar mini cart widget which appears when you add some product to cart. I tried this:

1. Disabled "Redirect to the cart page after successful addition" and "Enable AJAX Buy Now buttons on archives" from WooCommerce settings.
2. After that added this function into `functions.php` file:

   ```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'add_to_cart_checkout_redirection', 10, 1 );

   function add_to_cart_checkout_redirection( $url ) {
      return wc_get_checkout_url();
   }
   ```

But seems that products still appears in the right sidebar cart after pressing `Buy Now` button. How to override that, and redirect to checkout directly?

Comment: You should have asked the author.

Comment: I allready do, but their support is slow, so i think that here can get faster responce.